Ansible Shared Connection To host Closed In Large Playbook
I have a moderately sized Ansible playbook that I'm running with
ansible-playbook  -i inventories/stg db_servers.yml --vault-id stg@prompt --check --diff

that results in
TASK [database : Setup Log Rotations] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [stg_db_2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to {hostname} closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 0}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
stg_db_1             : ok=63   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=30   rescued=0    ignored=0
stg_db_2             : ok=84   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=53   rescued=0    ignored=0

I am able to connect to the target machines and the user I'm connecting with is manually able to create all of these files. I attempted to use the -vvv flags to find more useful information but it didn't have anything obvious.
I'm looking for what my next steps are to debug a problem like this. Thanks for the help.
Files
Task File
# Lots of other stuff here but truncated for lenght
- name: Setup Log Rotations
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
    file: log_rotations.yml
    apply:
      become: yes
  when: data_drive_mounted

log_rotations.yml
- name: Ensure logrotation.d Configuration Directory In /etc
  ansible.builtin.stat:
    path: /etc/logrotation.d
  register: logrotation_config_dir

- name: Add iANS Log Rotations
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: roles/seasensor_database/templates/ians_log_rotation.j2
    dest: /etc/logrotate.d/ians-log-rotation
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
  when: logrotation_config_dir.stat.writeable | default(false)

- name: Add PostgreSQL Remote Error Log Rotations
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: roles/seasensor_database/templates/remote_psql_error_log_rotation.j2
    dest: /etc/logrotate.d/psql-remote-log-rotation
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
  when: logrotation_config_dir.stat.writeable | default(false)

- name: Add PostgreSQL Cron Remote Log Rotations
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: roles/seasensor_database/templates/remote_psql_cron_log_rotation.j2
    dest: /etc/logrotate.d/psql-remote-cron-rotation
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
  when: logrotation_config_dir.stat.writeable | default(false)

Versions
ansible-playbook  --version
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Mar  8 2023, 18:40:28) [GCC 7.5.0]

ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Mar  8 2023, 18:40:28) [GCC 7.5.0]

